# PHP File Download In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I have a little problem with my download script in wordpress.
On my website, you can upload some files in custom posts and some users, after login, can download them.
I simplified, just for testing, the whole code by simply passing the ID of the custom post and dinamically getting the file to download.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
$file_url = str_replace("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "", $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT guid FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=(SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id=".$_GET['File']." AND meta_key='file') " ));
$file_path = join('/', array(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/'), trim($file_url, '/')));
$file_type = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT post_mime_type FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=(SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id=".$_GET['File']." AND meta_key='file') " );
$file_size  = filesize($file_path); header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_path));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile($file_path);
```

Now the problem is:
Downloaded file has correct name and correct size, but I just cannot view it.
I tried with a simple jpeg and, using WinMerge, it seems like 3 lines have different values, but I can't find differences:
ORIGINAL FILE:
    æ–çç©è2è¼éFéÐê[êåëpëûì†ííœî(î´ï@ïÌðXðåñrñÿòŒóó§ô4ôÂõPõÞömöû÷Šøø¨ù8ùÇúWúçûwüü˜ý)ýºþKþÜÿmÿÿdesc
DOWNLOADED FILE:
    æ–çç©è2è¼éFéÐê[êåëpëûì†ííœî(î´ï@ïÌðXðåñrñÿòŒóó§ô4ôÂõPõÞömöû÷Šøø¨ù8ùÇúWúçûwüü˜ý)ýºþKþÜÿmÿÿdesc

Here is a stamp of another line:
http://cadienvan.altervista.org/stackoverflow.png

I really cannot see any difference!
P.S. The Black line you see in the above image is just my cursor!

*I just found that in the row you can see in the image, in the upper one(So in the original file), there are 4 white spaces that have been canceled in the downloaded one.

Comment: I assume that's just sample code and your real code doesn't have those SQL injection vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1):

The content type of your file *should* be not generic `application/octet-stream`, but the type of the file itself, try changing this line:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

to (`$file_type` is already defined in your code)

```
header('Content-Type:'.$file_type);
```

EDIT : Also make sure that you do not have *any* spaces or new lines in the source code (at the beginning of your script or at the end), because those *may* be included in the output.

EDIT : Try to  remove all `header(...)` lines, except:

`Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition` and also add another one:

`header('Content-length:' . $file_size);`

Comment: I tried to do it too. I tried to write directly(In case of an image) Content-Type: image/jpeg, but it doesn't work. It just adds some whitespaces..

Comment: I already tried to save the same file with notepad, ANSI and UTF-8, but there are no spaces..

Comment: Can you remove all `header(...)` lines, except: Content-Type,Content-Disposition and also add another `header('Content-length:'. $file_size)`